# Is there a name for the data structure/encoding which encodes deltas between adjacent values?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, encoding, delta

I was curious if there is a name for encoding a list of numbers as the deltas between adjacent values. For example, given the following list:

`[5, 7, -2, 8, 10, 5]`

the "delta list' would be:

`[2, -9, 10, 2, -5]`

Perhaps a variant would be:

`[5, 2, -9, 10, 2, -5]`

if the first number of the original lst is to be included for a frame of reference.

Is there a specific name for either of these encodings, whether the name describes either the resulting data encoding or just the process of arriving at the given output? I'm aware of delta encodings, but I was wondering if there was a more specific term.

Comment: I think most people would just call that "delta encoding".  Make it clear that you're operating on a list of integers, and people will know what you mean.

Comment: What i would do is take the name of the first array and put delta before it "delta<name of your array>"